# Reactnative Bottom Tab Navigation not work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I'm using React Native with Expo trying to build bottom Tab Navigation but not sure what the causes the error, i using React Navigation6

App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs";
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import BottomBar from './src/Navbar/BottomBar';

export default function App() {
  return(
      <NavigationContainer>
         <BottomBar/>
      </NavigationContainer>
  )
};
```

The error:

```
Unable to resolve module src/Screens/Navigation/BottomNav from /Users/wafaturaifi/Desktop/Requests/App.js: src/Screens/Navigation/BottomNav could not be found within the project or in these directories:
  node_modules

If you are sure the module exists, try these steps:
 1. Clear watchman watches: watchman watch-del-all
 2. Delete node_modules and run yarn install
 3. Reset Metro's cache: yarn start --reset-cache
 4. Remove the cache: rm -rf /tmp/metro-*
```

BottomBar.js:

```
import React, { useEffect, useContext } from "react";
import { View } from "react-native";
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs";
import HomeScreen from '../Screens/Home';
import MoreScreen from '../Screens/More';
import PostScreen from '../Screens/Post';
import RequestsScreen from '../Screens/Requests';
import SummaryScreen from '../Screens/Summary';

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

const BottomBar=() => {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Summary" component={SummaryScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Add" component={AddScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Requests" component={RequestsScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="More" component={MoreScreen} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}
export default BottomBar;
```

Files structure:

[image]

Comment: Certainly there is problem with your `BottomNav` import, please fix that. And check if that's named or default export and import accordingly.

Comment: not sure where  the issue exactly, i check named, default export and import it is fine

Comment: mind sharing the code for BottomNav and the files names and extensions, and did you try to reset the cache and run again

Comment: sure , sorry but what is reset the cache!

Answer (score 1):

This issue was because to use React Navigation you need to run the following command

```
npm install react-native-reanimated react-native-gesture-handler react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context @react-native-community/masked-view
```

or

```
yarn add react-native-reanimated react-native-gesture-handler react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context @react-native-community/masked-view
```

Answer (score 1):

Try those steps:

1. remove node modules
2. npm install -force
3. and run again;

If those steps didn't solve problem, please can you share `package.json`.